# create a single colored symbol with a newcommand

Tags: macros, color

I have created a symbol with

```
\newcommand{\redx}[1][x]{\color{red}{\boldsymbol{#1}}}
```

This correctly colors the symbol red, but annoyingly it also colors the symbols after it red. How do I ensure only one symbol is colored.

Comment: `\color{red}` willl switch everything that follows, until the end of the group, to red. I does not have a second argument. What you are looking for is `\textcolor{red}{something}`.

Comment: I use it for mathematical symbols, but I see that \textcolor works in mathmode as well. This solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\color{red}` is a declaration. It tells LaTeX to start typesetting in red and bracing the following text does not delimit the red text; only a brace or other grouping *before* the declaration will define a scope for the declaration.

You want `\textcolor{red}{whatever}` which, despite the name, also works in math mode and continues math mode for its second argument.

Answer (score 1):

Hope that this will help you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\newcommand{\redx}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}

\begin{document}

    this is in \redx{red}.this is in black.
    
\end{document}
```

Its output is
[image: output]